# Tray icon area is missing/invisible, icons locked on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, notifications, notification-area

Since today I got the problem that my whole tray icon area is empty/missing/invisible. The only thing I see is the notification area icon and my locale settings:

[image: Hidden tray icon area]

Interestingly, the icons are completely locked/greyed out in the settings. I can't re-enable them:

[image]

Even icons from custom applications don't show up. I already followed [this](https://superuser.com/questions/94679/notification-area-volume-icon-is-stuck-off) and [this](http://www.technipages.com/windows-system-icons-missing-from-notification-area) (the same) instruction, but it didn't take any effect.

As there were two Windows updates installed on March 2nd, I tried to remove them, but I only can remove one of them (KB3140743). Didn't take any effect. The other update (KB3139907) is not removable.

Edit: I discovered that also all my favorites for the quick access on the left side of the explorer have been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found through a supporting member in the [Microsoft forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/tray-icon-area-is-missinginvisible-icons-locked-on/ae4d6380-17ca-4ebd-a21b-2e065423fa32): apply [this fix](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/restore-pin-to-taskbar-option-windows-10/) and sign out/sign in again.